# Emit a Javascript library as an ES6 module with different browser and Node.js implementations

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, browserify

What is the best way to create an ES6 library, e.g. `my-es6-crypto-lib`, which can be used both in the browser and in Node.js, but for which the implementations are different on each platform?

(E.g. the Node.js implementation uses the built-in `crypto` module for better performance.)

ES6 module usage:

```
import { sha256 } from 'my-es6-crypto-lib'
let digest = sha256('abc')
console.log(digest)
```

Or Node.js-style requires:

```
let sha256 = require('my-es6-crypto-lib')
let digest = sha256('abc')
console.log(digest)
```

The `package.json` for `my-es6-crypto-lib` would include:

```
{
   "name": "my-es6-crypto-lib",
   "main": "transpiled-to-commonjs/node.js",
   "module": "es6-module/node.js",
   "browser": "es6-module/browser.js",
   ...
}
```

- Node.js will follow the `main` key to resolve the CommonJS module.
- Tools capable of consuming ES6 modules (like transpiler/bundling tools) follow the `module` key.
- Tools which consume ES6 modules and bundle them for browsers (e.g. [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve)) will follow the `browser` key.

The actual implementation for Node.js would look something like: (`transpiled-to-commonjs/node.js`)

```
// built-in module, faster than the pure Javascript implementation
let createHash = require('crypto')

export function sha256 (message) {
  return createHash('sha256').update(message).digest('hex')
}
```

While the browser implementation would look something like: (`es6-module/browser.js`)

```
// a javascript-only implementation available at es6-module/hashFunctions.js
import { sha256 } from './hashFunctions'

export function sha256 (message) {
  // slightly different API than the native module
  return sha256(message, 'hex')
}
```

Note, the implementation of each function is different on each platform, but both `sha256` methods have the same parameter `message` and return a string.

**What is the best way to structure my ES6 module to provide each of these implementations? Are there any javascript libraries out there which do this?**

Ideally:

- the unused implementation should be able to be tree shaken, and
- no runtime checks should be used to determine the current environment.

#### (I also opened a [GitHub issue for Rollup →](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1308))

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory solution?

Comment: @MaiaVictor yes, I think so. Just answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868336/1326803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I now think the best way to do this is actually to export different functionality for each environment.

> In the past, complex javascript libraries have used solutions like Browserify to bundle a version of their application for the browser. Most of these solutions work by allowing library developers to extensively configure and manually override various dependencies with respective browser versions.
>
> For example, where a Node.js application might use Node.js' built-in crypto module, a browser version would need to fall back to a polyfill-like alternative dependency like crypto-browserify.
>
> With es6, this customization and configuration is no longer necessary. Your library can now export different functionality for different consumers. While browser consumers may import a native JavaScript crypto implementation which your library exports, Node.js users can choose to import a different, faster implementation which your library exports.
>
> ...

It's explained in depth, and with an example, in the [**typescript-starter readme →**](https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter#how-can-my-library-provide-different-functionality-between-nodejs-and-the-browser)